# Why is there no stack segment in an object (ELF) files?

Tags: c, operating-system, elf

I am beginner of OS. This question is given by my professor and confused me a lot. I hope I can get some hints and helps here.

In my memory, ELF file can link each other. Is that a reason that ELF file cannot have stack segment?

Thanks a lot for any helps!

Comment: Suppose that object files did have stack segments.  What would you put in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because stack is not something need to be saved in a file format, it is completely related to runtime execution. Just like you don't need to have a "heap segment" in your file.

On the other hand, stack belongs to an executing thread, *not* data or functions, and it doesn't has a fixed size. Consider a recursive function:

```
int foo() {
    printf("Stack Overflow!\n");
    return foo();
}
```

every recursion has its own frame in stack, there is no stack belong to `foo()` itself, only for its execution.

Of course you **can** reserve a stack segment in your file, just as a big block of static memory, and let the `%rsp` pointer(x64) pointing to it. But OS has already done for you, so it's not necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really helpful and clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Most GNU/Linux ELF programs do have stack segments because on all but very recent architectures, a stack segment in the program header is used to mark the stack as non-executable (which is a form of security hardening).

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000ffd0c 0x00000000000ffd0c  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000100548 0x0000000000700548 0x0000000000700548
                 0x000000000000b6fc 0x0000000000015440  RW     0x200000
…
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000100548 0x0000000000700548 0x0000000000700548
                 0x0000000000002ab8 0x0000000000002ab8  R      0x1
```

On certain GNU/Linux architectures (FDPIC), the size of the stack segment is even used by the kernel to set the stack size of the main thread.

(There are different kinds of program segments.  Not all of them load bits from the file image.)